# Why elements of a 2D array are linked

Tags: python

I am taking a quick course Python programming and I learn a quick way to initialize an array in Python by using the * operator. I am trying to extend it to a 2d case.

```
A = [[0]*3]*3
```

I then try to modify the [0][1] element to specific value but I found that all elements on the middle column are changed at the same time. For example,

```
A[0][1] = 888
```

It results in A[0][1] = 888, A[1][1] = 888, A[2][1] = 888. I really don't see how this happens. It seems like that all elements are linked and refer to the same address. But if I change the initialization code to

```
A = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

The problem is gone. I just wonder what is wrong with the first approach. Any fast way to initialize the array with certain value but without explicitly specify the elements?

Comment: Thanks. I will close my question

Comment: try to do it with list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
a = [[0 for i in range(3)] for o in range(3)]
```